# Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema

Tags: node.js, reactjs, package.json

I have been stuck on this error in my project when I add `"proxy": "http://localhost:6000"`
in my package.json.

This is the error response after yarn start.

> Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an
> options object that does not match the API schema.
>
> - options.allowedHosts[0] should be a non-empty string. error Command failed with exit code 1. info Visit
>   https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this
>   command.

But everything is fine when I remove the `"proxy": "http://localhost:6000"`.

This is on my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true, 
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-file-base64": "^1.0.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:6000"
}
```

Comment: If everything is fine if you remove it, why not remove it?

Comment: Because it may be needed? I need it to proxy my api requests to my backend in my react app. But yeah i am looking for solution to this too

Comment: This https://githubmemory.com/repo/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11762 article has the reason but does not yet have a solution

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Here is a workaround. Delete `"proxy": "http://localhost:6000"`. Install package `http-proxy-middleware` with command `npm install http-proxy-middleware --save`. Create a file `setupProxy.js` inside your src folder or the root of your folder. Add these lines inside:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:6000',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

Now, run your app. It should work.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround @josipat. It seems that using `/` for the context (the route matching value) causes some issues. Unless I am missing something, you will have to use a non-root path like you suggest above (/api). When trying to emulate what I was using with the `proxy` value in my _package.json_ file, I receive a client error: `domain option is required`.

Comment: Also, to point out, you may want to do: `app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/api', { ...` instead to receive proper logging from the middleware.

Comment: This worked for me. I upgraded webpack and node, removed proxy from my package.json, then upgraded my existing api calls to route to /api.

Comment: my app still runs on port 3000 instead of 8000

Comment: This may be a silly question, but when we create this file then re-run our react app, when we make our fetch call, how does the proxy really work? How does it automatically register when we run the dev server without needing to import it anywhere?

Comment: I see the same "Invalid options object..." error message but ONLY when I attempt to run offline. When I am online everything works fine. Why is that?

Comment: Specifying "localhost:6000" oesn't work:

[HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:3000/api/endpoint to http://localhost:6000/ [ECONNREFUSED]

Loading http://localhost:6000/api/endpoint directly in the browser works just fine.

EDIT: NodeJS version 17 and up no longer prefers IPv4 over IPv6 for DNS lookups, so you have to specify 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost (since localhost gets mapped to "::1" now). Ref: http://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/#nodejs-17-econnrefused-issue-with-ipv6-and-localhost-705

Comment: for who has the problem like this: "my app still runs on port 3000 instead of 8000", that's because of the wrong path for `setupProxy.js`. in my case with react app, i create this file in `src folder`

Answer (score 36):

The other solutions did not work for me so here's what I found:

This seems to be a CRA bug (security feature?) where `allowedHosts` gets set to `[undefined]` because `prepareUrls` doesn't set `lanUrlForConfig` when both a host and a proxy are specified. The relevant CRA GitHub issue is [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11762).

If appropriate in your use case (read [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/9673858a3715287c40aef9e800c431c7d45c05a2/packages/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js#L25) to learn more), this can be avoided by creating a `.env` file and adding `DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true` to it or trying `DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true yarn start`.

Comment: What does DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK do? Is it a viable solution? the "dangerously" part makes me doubtful

Comment: I use the proxy option only for local development so I think this option is safe for me!

Comment: Solved it for me! Thanks

Comment: @NullDefault, wow that solved it, I have been dealing with this for hours.

Answer (score 34):

Setting `"allowedHosts"` as a property in `package.json` didn't work for me. I had to wrap it in an `options` property:

```
"options": {
    "allowedHosts": ["localhost", ".localhost"],
    "proxy": "https://localhost:3386/"
  }
```

After that, `npm start` did the trick without having to re-install modules.

**Update:** I did some additional research based on some of the comments and other answers (notably [Anjul's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70945916/470477)). I wasn't able to find documentation supporting an `"options"` entry in [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json?v=true); however, it looks to me like it *may* be there as a side-effect of using [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverallowedhosts).

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, this might be the best solution.

Comment: This is the only solution which worked for me, thank you.

Comment: This solution works for me, but I did notice that ".localhost" isn't necessary.

Comment: @Leejjon I suspect the `.localhost` entry is valuable if you want to allow for subdomains such as `www`.

Comment: I hate webpack so much, friendship with webpack has ended, vite is my new best friend

Comment: This is worked man , thanks a lot!

Comment: This just disables the actual proxy, and doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: @StanislavModrák I think I understand what you mean, but I'm not certain. Are you saying that it would override the proxy on deployment?

Answer (score 19):

A quick solution is to **downgrade your `webpack`** version using `react-scripts`

In the `package.json` file of your react-app, change the `react-scripts` version.

**Replace**

```
"react-scripts": "5.*",
```

---

**To**

```
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
```

Remove `node_modules` and install the packages again for your react app.

Comment: Nice solution, let's wait till this is fixed for v5

Comment: @enginbilici `5.0.1` didn't fix :-(

Comment: with this solution I get the "Error: spawn mozilla ENOENT" when starting the development server

Comment: This is not a solution fits to everyone, only those which happen to use `react-scripts` as their Webpack configuration.

Comment: thanks it works but after downgrade i got almost 100 valnerabilities that contains 9 criticals and they stay even after `npm audit fix`. with `npm audit fix --force` vunerabilities fixed but it upgrades the `react-scripts` to 5th version. so what should i do with these critical valenabilities that may cause problem in future?

Answer (score 11):

Run `npm audit fix --force`
And while still connected to the internet
Run `npm start`

Should work fine

Comment: its broke my package.json file

Answer (score 6):

For me removing `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` folder - then running `npm i` solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Reverting back to an older version of node worked for me.
First of all clear npm's cache and install older version of node.

```
    > sudo npm cache clean -f
    > sudo npm install -g n
    > sudo n <version>
```

Latest **version 18** was not working for me; **version 14.8.2** works for me as I was using this version previously. You can try with any version below 18

Answer (score 4):

I just debugged the issue in JS Debugger.

Node v18 changed `os.networkInterfaces()` `family`:

> v18.0.0
> The family property now returns a number instead of a string.

This is throwing off `address` module used by `react-scripts` which checks family against "IPv4"

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem with the http-proxy-middleware solution as others. But to get it working properly, I had to close down my VPN. Same answer as Saeed Kolivand has above. =)

Comment: For me, no change is required. Only disabling the VPN did the job. Tried everything mentioned here... until I read this answer and found VPN is the culprit.

Comment: Yes, removing installed VPN solved my problem ! !

Answer (score 3):

So my team had the same issue, with the same error of `options.allowedHosts[0] should be a non-empty string.` The solution we outline below is a very specific error and most likely does not pertain to many people.

In our case, the `allowedHosts[0]` variable was undefined and we traced the `allowedHosts[0]` variable to be equal to `allowedHost` in `node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpackDevServer.config.js`.

```
module.exports = function (proxy, allowedHost) {
  const disableFirewall =
    !proxy || process.env.DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK === 'true';
  return {
    // WebpackDevServer 2.4.3 introduced a security fix that prevents remote
    // websites from potentially accessing local content through DNS rebinding:
    // https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/887
    // https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server-middleware-security-issues-1489d950874a
    // However, it made several existing use cases such as development in cloud
    // environment or subdomains in development significantly more complicated:
    // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2271
    // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2233
    // While we're investigating better solutions, for now we will take a
    // compromise. Since our WDS configuration only serves files in the `public`
    // folder we won't consider accessing them a vulnerability. However, if you
    // use the `proxy` feature, it gets more dangerous because it can expose
    // remote code execution vulnerabilities in backends like Django and Rails.
    // So we will disable the host check normally, but enable it if you have
    // specified the `proxy` setting. Finally, we let you override it if you
    // really know what you're doing with a special environment variable.
    // Note: ["localhost", ".localhost"] will support subdomains - but we might
    // want to allow setting the allowedHosts manually for more complex setups
    allowedHosts: disableFirewall ? 'all' : [allowedHost],
```

`urls.lanUrlForConfig` is passed in to the config file from `node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js` to `allowedHost`.

```
const createDevServerConfig = require('../config/webpackDevServer.config');
...
createDevServerConfig(proxyConfig, urls.lanUrlForConfig)
```

`urls.lanUrlForCofig` is produced by the `prepareUrls` function in `node_modules\react-dev-utils\WebpackDevServerUtils.js`.

```
const urls = prepareUrls(
  protocol,
  HOST,
  port,
  paths.publicUrlOrPath.slice(0, -1)
);
```

In the `prepareUrls` function, `urls.lanUrlForConfig` is set as undefined in the case that the computer's IPv4 address is non-private as seen below:

```
try {
  // This can only return an IPv4 address
  lanUrlForConfig = address.ip();
  if (lanUrlForConfig) {
    // Check if the address is a private ip
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces
    if (
      /^10[.]|^172[.](1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])[.]|^192[.]168[.]/.test(
        lanUrlForConfig
      )
    ) {
      // Address is private, format it for later use
      lanUrlForTerminal = prettyPrintUrl(lanUrlForConfig);
    } else {
      // Address is not private, so we will discard it
      lanUrlForConfig = undefined;
    }
  }
} catch (_e) {
  // ignored
}
```

So in the end, we determined that the reason why we were having the error was because the ip address that we being pulled from the machine was non-private due to some ethernet cable configurations (We were getting a 169. address, an APIPA one, that was because the machine couldn't reach a DHCP server). This caused the `urls.lanUrlForConfig` to be undefined, which would ultimately get passed all the way down to the allowedHosts[0] variable and cause the error.

Fixing the inability of not being able to connect to the DHCP server is another  issue itself, but as a hotfix for development purposes only, we added a `DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true` into our `.env` file and it worked fine after restarting the development server. Setting `"allowedHosts": "all"` in our package.json was another solution.

Comment: I tried all the options available here nothing worked, except DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true solution. I am running reactjs and express code in a cloud machine with global ipaddress. Your explanation makes sense for my case, though I have not debugged much.

Answer (score 2):

To overcome this problem you just have to be connected to internet when you run `npm start`.

Comment: This helped me, my issue was I was on the "CoxWifi" so some internet worked, but this must have blocked whatever npm needs....connecting to the proper wifi fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you add or remove `"proxy": "http://localhost:6000"` in `package.json`,
then remove node_modules and reinstall it.
This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and josipat's answer worked for me, except I needed to install it as a development dependency. The solution where one saves the following code to src/setUpProxy.js originates from [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually).

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:5000',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

[reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) [create-react-app](/questions/tagged/create-react-app)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error only when switching to Node 18.0.0 with nvm. Getting rid of `"proxy":"http://localhost:5000"` fixes it, but it's not an option for me and I'd like to avoid the proxy middleware on server. If you switch to a previous Node version like 17.0.0 it works fine. I think that could be a better option until CRA team does not address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

this error with Node version 18.0.0 , I try with version Node 16.15.0 it works fine

Answer (score 0):

For 5.0.1 react-scripts the bug has not been reproduced, but error occurs in 5.0.0. I guess you could use 5.0.1 to solve this problem

Comment: *I guess you could use 5.0.1 to solve this problem* I still get the error with 5.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue several times but finally I found a solution!!

I solved this problem by adding `"allowedHosts": "all"` to my package.json file

Example:

```js
"allowedHosts": "all",
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001/api",
"name": "simple-blog",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.1
```

Another solution is by adding `DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true` to your .env file it solves the problem too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using webpack.config.js different..

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware'); 
module.exports = {
plugins: [
    new createProxyMiddleware({
        target: 'http://localhost:6000',
        changeOrigin: true,
      })
],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have faced the same problem but without doing any other code or structural manipulation, I first created a new react-app. I just installed all the dependencies which are found in the json file of the one which is not working and I deleted the node module , the backagelock.json file from the react-app which is not working. I removed all the content in json file and copied and pasted all things from the new react-app json file  to the old json file  and after saving I did npm install on the terminal and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Turning my VPN off worked for me

Answer (score -3):

I had the same issue, You can add **"allowedHosts": "all"** after **"proxy": "https://yourdomain"** in your **package.json**. hopefully it solves your problem.

update: the problem was with the company VPN. When I disconnect the VPN, it works normally.