# "options.allowedHosts[0] should be a non-empty string." when adding proxy to package.json in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I was following a tutorial for React.js and Django Rest Framework (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYKRAXIio28&ab_channel=DennisIvy), then on 1:18:10 (Frontend part) he added `proxy` to the **package.json** in root folder and everything was working fine.
But then when I did the same I came across a problem, when I tried to do `npm start` it gives me back this error,

```
Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options.allowedHosts[0] should be a non-empty string.
```

My **package.json** look like this

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
```

I tried searching the answer on my own and the closest one I found is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70387809/reactjs-server-is-not-starting-while-using-proxy-api which, as you can see, it was voluntarily removed by its author.
Another one I found is https://gitmemory.cn/index.php/repo/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11762 talking about `HOST` in **.env** file have conflict error ( I don't really understand since I'm quite new to this stuff ). But I do **not** have **.env** file.

I've also tried [React Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/ from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8000 (ECONNREFUSED)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107816/react-proxy-error-could-not-proxy-request-api-from-localhost3000-to-http-l?rq=1) by doing

```
"proxy": "http://django:8000",
```

which doesn't seem to have any effect.

I've confirmed that the problem is indeed proxy because the problem don't occur when I remove this line and the app runs properly.

I believe options.allowedHosts should be set to an array which I have no idea what to put and where to put it so if you understand the problem please be kind and elaborate on that, thank you.

Also, `http://127.0.0.1:8000` is my localhost for django backend, in case that help.

**Edit 1:** Tried

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
"allowedHosts": [
    "127.0.0.1"
  ],
"private":true,
```

and

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
"private":false,
```

Both of them didn't work

**TLDR;**
`proxy` in **package.json** broke my React app pls send help

Note: This is my first time asking question on stackoverflow so I apologize if the question is stupid or I asked something wrong.

Comment: I've found a solution, https://stackoverflow.com/a/70413065/16074007.
I'm flagging my own question as duplicate.

Comment: It's not a solution, it's a workaround

Answer (score 15):

I am facing the same problem. But my problem exist when I am not connected to the internet. When I connect to the internet, the dev server starts with the command yarn start or npm start.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can confirm it's when not connected to the internet!

Comment: mine started working when reconnected to internet. it's weird. is there any explanation for this?? thanks btw

Comment: almost same, mine started working after I disconnected my VPN