# Proxy does not work in localhost with create-react-app and deno server

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I want to access Apis in Deno server from a React app. I added `proxy` to the package.json file but I got this error:

```
options.allowedHosts[0] should be a non-empty string.
```

I found a similar question [Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70374005/invalid-options-object-dev-server-has-been-initialized-using-an-options-object/70413065#70413065), I followed the answer by installing the  `http-proxy-middleware` in the react project and add the `setupProxy` under the src folder:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:5000',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

I followed also what mentioned in the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/), however I still have the same error:

```
Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options.allowedHosts[0] should be a non-empty string.
```

I'm using `react-scripts v5.0.0` and `typescript v4.6.2`.