# How do I downgrade react-scripts 5.0.1 to 4.0.3

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I'm having the issue that's faced in this question: [Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70374005/invalid-options-object-dev-server-has-been-initialized-using-an-options-object)

One of the solutions is to downgrade react-scripts to 4.0.3 and I'm not sure how to do that. Could someone help me?

Comment: If the solution is to downgrade react-scripts from 5.x to 4.x, that's almost certainly not the actual solution. Which version of node are you using? Because Node 16 (the current LTS) should work fine, whereas Node 18 (the current active) does not. And if you don't want to constantly reinstall Node, use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating) or [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows#installation--upgrades) (depending on your OS) to make using different Node versions without constantly reinstalling a trivial task.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could always delete your `node_modules` directory and change the version in your *package.json* under dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react-scripts" :"5.0.1",
}
```

then run an install. It's better to do a terminal approach when looking to change versions of a package, like:

### NPM

uninstall:

```
npm uninstall react-scripts
```

install:

```
npm install --save react-scripts@4.0.3
```

### Yarn

since Yarn is the preferred for *Create React Ap*p per memory:

uninstall:

```
yarn remove react-scripts
```

install:

```
yarn add react-scripts@4.0.3
```

Answer (score 2):

You have at least 2 options.

First, in your project folder you run the following command:

```
npm i react-scripts@4.0.3
```

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts/v/4.0.3?activeTab=versions

Second, you open your package.json file in your project and change the version number of react-scripts to 4.0.3

```
"dependencies": {
   "react-scripts" :"4.0.3",
   ...
}
```

and run `npm i`.

This will upgrade or downgrade everything to the version that are stated in your package.json file.

Comment: Or using the current LTS versions of Node (14 or 16) rather than the current active dev version.

Comment: Instead of manually updating the package.json, why not run `npm i -S react-scripts@4.0.3` which should update your package.json dependencies?