# Any fix for the issue caused by `react-scripts 5.0.1`?

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-scripts

I've been developing a React app successfully for months.  Suddenly it wouldn't start tonight, displaying the message shown here: [Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70374005/invalid-options-object-dev-server-has-been-initialized-using-an-options-object)

This other message also flashed by really quickly:

[image]

I spent several hours trying every suggestion I could find and finally tried this one:

In `package.json`, change `"react-scripts": "^5.0.1",` to: `"react-scripts": "^4.0.3",`

And voila, it worked again!

Many have written that this is a known bug with React Scripts v5.  Just wondering if anyone knows when it might be fixed?

Comment: From my limited looking around, it doesn't look like there is a good workaround other than going back to `4.0.3`. Found issues [#11860](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11860) and [#12035](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12035) about this. PR to address it is [#11862](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/11862), but is stuck and doesn't look like there's been much progress on it recently.

Comment: Thanks, @HenryWoody.  At work, we use Dependabot to automatically generate NPM updates.  It's highly recommending upgrading `react-scripts` to `5.0.1`.  I've shared my sad tale and recommended we wait until `5.0.2`.